# Multi user application with push notifications with Azure Push Notifications

Tags: mobile, azure, notifications, push

I have a multi user application with some user settings inside. I am interested in Windows Azure Push Notification Services and my question is can I change within my app the connection to this service to tell to which user to send the Push notification. I mean I dont want 2 users using same app, on same device to read each others notifications

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial below shows you how to use Windows Azure Notification Hubs to send push notifications to a specific app user on a specific device. A Windows Azure Mobile Services backend is used to authenticate clients and to generate notifications.

[Notify users with Notification Hubs](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-mobile-services-notify-users/)